# Get all available admin pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I need to create a dropdown with all available admin pages in Wordpress:

```
Dashboard -> /wp-admin/index.php
Posts -> /wp-admin/edit.php
Media -> /wp-admin/upload.php
...
etc
...
```

I can do it manually but I would like get the specific plugins links that have first order menu:

```
My plugin -> /wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin
```

Comment: you want this dropdown to appear where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is stored in the global `$menu` and `$submenu` variables (though they're only available in the admin screens, of course).

Have a look at [the _wp_menu_output function in menu-header.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4/wp-admin/menu-header.php#L36) to see how WordPress uses them.

You'll need to consider the user's permissions too.  See the usages of the `current_user_can` function in [_wp_menu_output](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4/wp-admin/menu-header.php#L36).